# How to change persistence property of cq:inplaceEditing

Tags: dialog, aem, inplace-editing

I wish to use **cq:inplaceEditing** to modify a property on my JCR whenever it is used by the AEM authors.  Unfortunately, I do not know how to modify the *name* of the *property* that it actually modifies in the JCR.  It appears that it only modifies the value of the property "text" by default.

For my purposes, I want to use its rich-text-editing for properties that have names I define, not just the default name "text."

The image at this link shows the tree which contains the cq:inplaceEditing (courtesy of CRXDE):

[image]

These are the attributes of cq:editConfig:

[image]

These are the attributes of cq:inplaceEditing:

[image]

...and this is what a content node of my JCR looks like when I use the inplaceEditor.  I've blotted out the names of some properties for potential security reasons.  Note that the "text" property below was changed when I used the inplaceEditor.  Also note that I want to be able to define the property name that the inplaceEditor changes, rather than just the "text" property:

[image]

Is there a way to use a different property name instead of "text"?

**-----------EDIT----------**

After changing the property "textPropertyName" to the property that I am searching for, it still doesn't appear to actually modify the behavior of the inplaceEditor.  It still only modifies the "text" property of my JCR nodes instead of the one that I put in the "textPropertyName" attribute.

This picture contains the attributes of my cq:InplaceEditingConfig:

[image]

The picture below contains the attributes of the JCR node at the path specified in the "configPath" variable in the picture above.  Note that I set the textPropertyName attribute in this node and the text component still modifies the default attribute "text" instead of the one specified:

[image]

Finally, the picture below shows the contents of my JCR tree inside of the text component.

[image]

**-----------ANOTHER EDIT----------**

I discovered that the inline text editor was persisting the correct property after I had switched to the classic UI.  For some reason, it doesn't work correctly with the touch UI.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## How to find it

The inplace editing capability is defined by subclasses of `CQ.ipe.InplaceEditing` function. You can find it easily by just searching for `editorType` through the CRXDE tool.

Searching for the `CQ.ipe.InplaceEditing` returns multiple results such as `CQ.ipe.TextEditor` that at the very end of the script registers desired `editorType` i.e.: `CQ.ipe.InplaceEditing.register("text", CQ.ipe.TextEditor);`

## The answer

Reading through the editor code you can find the first configurable property called `textPropertyName` which according to it's documentation is just what you are looking for. Combining it with the inplace configuration node (see [Adobe's documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/components.html#cq:inplaceEditing)) it is the solution for your case.

## An example

You can try it by yourself on an instance of Geometrixx component.

1. First go to CRXDE and find Geometrixx Text component: `/apps/geometrixx-gov/components/text`.
2. Notice `/apps/geometrixx-gov/components/text/cq:editConfig/cq:inplaceEditing@configPath` property value.
3. Find `/apps/geometrixx-gov/components/text/dialog/items/tab1/items/text` resource and add new property: `textPropertyName=myPropertyName`.
4. Then just open the [Geometrixx Gov page](http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx-gov/en.html) add Geometrixx Text component, edit it inplace and look into the Network console. You'll notice POST request with the altered parameter name

---

*edit after TouchUI clarification*

## TouchUI case

If you want to achieve the same for TouchUI interface it doesn't go so easy, unfortunately. The `text` inplace editor for TouchUI is defined by `/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/clientlibs/editor/js/editors/InlineTextEditor.js`.

Searching for `"text"` gives you an overview how hardcoded is this property. For AEM 6.1 (on which I'm testing it) you can find it's occurence in the `ns.persistence.readParagraphContent` function where the `initialContent` is extracted from the resource JSON map. Another occurence can be found in `finishInlineEdit` and `addHistoryStep` methods. Changing all three occurences of `"text"` to your value brings expected outcome.

This is obviously non-acceptable - it's a platform-wide change and will affect other (incl. ootb) components where it might no be expected. The simplest would be to just copy-paste whole editor into your clientlib and register the editor into a new name - see last couple of lines: `ns.editor.register`. If you feel comfortable in JS, it might be worth to extend this editor and alter just three methods that are affected.

Comment: This looks great.  I don't go into work till Monday, but when I do, I will verify to see if this answer solves my issue.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, since it seems to make sense.  Something else appears to be wrong though.  I put the property textPropertyName in the path as mentioned in step 3, but the website still uses the ./text property instead of the property with the name that I mentioned.  Do I need to recompile anything?  What is wrong with it?

Another question:  The TextEditor.js script doesn't appear to load in my browser when I navigate to a page with a text component.  Does it ever show up in the client?  Or is it all done completely server-side?

Comment: Have you pointed the `configPath` property to the node where `textPropertyName` is defined? Please post the repository state of your component similar to the screenshots from the question.

The JS for inplace editing is definitely used client-side so should be loaded to your browser. I'm not 100% sure if `TextEditor.js` is the proper handler for it though, this was just a first item from search.

Comment: See my edit above, and thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: try to remove the `./` prefix which is specific and typical for Sling but not for JS frameworks so the `textPropertyName` prop should have the value of `courseTitle`

Comment: Tried that.  Still not modifying it.  Perhaps I'm just not modifying it correctly?  I click and drag the text component onto the page, click on it, write some text inside of the component, and click "X."  I then looked at the JCR in CRX/DE and found that the property that I specified with textPropertyName was still not there, but the "text" property was edited instead.

Comment: So, I discovered that your solution works perfectly for classic UI.  I hadn't tested that until now.  I do need it to work for touch UI, though.

Comment: I'm thrilled that you have extended your answer for the TOUCH UI. As I trying to create a component that's inplace editor accesses the same property node on both Classic and Touch, and I have changed the default name to not be TEXT.

Which means if I want I have to leave it to the default of TEXT. I agree. Unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you, Mateusz Chromiński, for that edit.  It explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As of AEM 6.3, the `textPropertyName` works correctly with the out-of-the-box PlainTextEditor.js

The property needs to be set on a `config` node under the `cq:InplaceEditingConfig`

[image: Location of the config node under cq:InplaceEditingConfig]

[image: textPropertyName property and value]

---

Note –  the source of the editor can now be found at:
`/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/editors/clientlibs/core/inlineediting/js/PlainTextEditor.js`

Comment: The property is ignored when you set the property  configPath on the node above (cq:inplaceEditing). If you use it with inline configuration it works. The alternative is to place this property on the resource where your configPath points to.